# как очистить консоль (cmd, Windows) вызываемой программой(exe, полученный из скрипта *.py) написанной на Python

Tags: python, консоль, exe

Есть файл .exe (ранее скрипт на Питоне) который запускает консоль и там многократно выводиться
информация и необходимо чтобы эта консоль перерисовывалась заново, а не выводилась строками ниже!!!
Проше говоря как бы затирая старый вывод новым! Чтобы не копились в консоли эти строчки вывода, а была
одна актульная!

**Работает обычный цикл:** while true
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо :) большущее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если полагаться на команду ОС

```
import os
os.system('cls||clear')
```

Для ANSI терминалов

```
print("\033c", end="", flush=True) #сброс
```

или

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J", end="", flush=True) #очистка
print(chr(27) + "[H", end="", flush=True) #перевод курсора в верхний угол
```